# expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: step over. The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation

Tags: xcode, swift

I am just going to new in swift,

I have one button on click of which opening front camera of iPad and clicking the photo of user, and when clicked on use photo,

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```

is getting called of `imagePickerController`

this is the line of code..

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        photoImgView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        if imageData == nil {
            imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!, 1)
        }
    }
```

but when I submit it shows found `nil value`,
after debugging got this point in `func didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`
which says,

```
(lldb) po imageData
expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: step over.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.
as I am not good in swift, can any one please guide me for the same.
I am stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution,
Thanks to my colleague,

I am capturing the image from imagePickerController and getting saved in `NSData`.
But the image captured it around 6-7 MB (iPad camera captures the image with this size by default)
and when saving it into `NSData` and then converting it into base64 format goes out of size and then compiler throws the issue.

Issue solved just by changing in line code for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    photoImgView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!, 0.5)
    print(imageData)
    picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `dissmissViewController(:_)` in the beginning. Call it at the end of function and try.

Comment: I tried it already, even I tried to convert into PNG format. but still issue exists

Comment: I think you've stepped over the instruction. 
- Step Over

    Executes the current statement and then stops at the next statement. If     the current statement is a function or script call then the debugger executes the whole function or script, and it stops at the next statement after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for video:

use "**PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey**" key

```
[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:avRequest resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                NSString *localPath = info[@"PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey"];
                if (localPath == nil || [localPath isEqualToString:@""]) {
                    isiCloud = YES;
                } else {
                    isiCloud = NO;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I passed an NSManagedObject which was created from the main NSManagedObjectContext to delegate.  The delegate reads the NSManagedObject from a background background thread.
[image]

To fix it, I make sure the delegate reads the NSManagedObject from the main thread.  This does the trick.[image]